# The Jensen family has many sons

Tags: riddle

The eldest son of Donald Louie Jensen, called Sven Donald Jensen, has like his father three sons.

Both of the youngest of the sons are called the same, Hewey and Dewey respectively, but Sven's oldest son is named after his grandpa's dad.

What are Sven's sons called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the name is:

> Louie Sven Jensen

because:

> the middle name of Sven is the same as his father's first name, Donald, therefore the Donald's father's name must be Louie.

Comment: was about to post this  ^^.